# String Replace in jquery or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to replace the word "residue1" to "calcule" in jquery or javascript but the actual word was "residue11" .

I user this function but it's not effective

```
 var calculeId = residueId.replace('residue1', 'calcule');
```

Comment: it works http://jsfiddle.net/achakravarty/zEAW5/

Comment: Whats wrong in using str.replace()?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify this? Do you mean you used the above code and it replaced "residue11" when you only wanted it to replace "residue1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be like

```
var residueId = "residue11";
var calculeId = residueId.replace('residue1', 'calcule');
alert(calculeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

use in javascript like this

```
var str="residue11";
var n=str.replace("residue1","calcule");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
var residueId = 'residue11'
alert(residueId.replace(/residue1|residue11/, 'calcule'))
```

[Example - jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/EMzLy/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var calculeId = 'residue11'.replace('residue1', 'calcule');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="residue11";

var n=str.replace(/residue1/g,"calcule");
```